# rewrite url using htacess.

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In this point i have this structure. `/quote-submit-php/` what i'd like to do is to rename the last '-' into '.' so it's going to be like this `quote-submit.php`
basically a single character. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(php)$ $1.$2 [L]
```